# Git Svn woes, why oh why can I never dcommit?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I have a git svn repository.

```
git svn clone http://myrepo/ myrepo
```

I dont want to work in master:

```
git checkout -b development
```

hack for a while.

```
git checkout master
git svn rebase
git rebase development
git svn dcommit
```

so far all good, it appears noone has committed since i did last, svn rebase doesnt make any changes and my rebase from development works a-ok.

```
Merge conflict during commit: File or directory 'inc/data.inc' is out of date; try updating: resource out of date; try updating at /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 576
```

Well, no Mr SVN, its not. I asked you for the latest one and you said I had it already. Its different because I changed it.

What is going on here, why can I not commit?

Comment: You don't need to switch back to master to dcommit. If you type `git svn info` while on the development branch you'll see that it's also connected to the svn trunk. So, just dcommit directly from that branch rather than switching back to master.

Comment: I find sometimes that git svn rebase can be finnicky, so i'd rather keep the svn line separate and do any merging/patching in git. thats why the 2 branches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're misusing `git rebase`. Try this instead:

> I dont want to work in master:
>
> ```
> git checkout -b development
> ```
>
> hack for a while.
>
> ```
> git checkout master
> git svn rebase
> git checkout development
> git rebase master
> git svn dcommit
> ```

Or, the shorthand for

```
git checkout development
git rebase master
```

is

```
git rebase master development
```

Comment: oh dear, you know you're running low on sleep when you stuff up basic syntax like that. Thanks so much.

Comment: Or just: `git svn rebase; git svn dcommit;` from the development branch, it's already tracking svn trunk.